# Is it true that $\limsup (a_n+b_n)\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)+\limsup(b_n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I know that it is true that $$\limsup (a_n+b_n)\leq \limsup(a_n)+\limsup(b_n)$$ In what cases is this inequality strict? Also, can we extend this to $$\limsup (a_n+b_n)= \lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)+\limsup(b_n)$$

Comment: For strictness, try $a_n = -b_n = (-1)^n$. If the sequence has a limit then $\limsup_n a_n = \lim a_n$.

Comment: @Cornman: That would imply the well known first inequality is false. Note that $\sup_n b_n\neq -\infty$.

Comment: @copper.hat I still can't see how the example you gave makes the inequality strict. Can you give me some more hints?

Comment: Just compute the three values??? What is $a_n+b_n$? What is $\limsup_n a_n$? What is $\limsup_n b_n$?

Comment: @copper.hat $a_n+b_n=2(-1)^n$ and $\limsup a_n=1$ and $\limsup b_n=1$. Can you tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: If $a_n = -b_n$ then surely you can see that $a_n+b_n = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:** If $(a_n)_n$ converges to $a$, then
$$\limsup(a_n+b_n) = a + \limsup(b_n). $$

*Proof:* We already know that
$$\limsup(a_n+b_n) \leq a + \limsup(b_n).$$
For the other inequality, let $(b_{n_k})_k$ be a subsequence of $(b_n)_n$ such that
$$b_{n_k} \longrightarrow \limsup(b_n).$$
Then $(a_{n_k} + b_{n_k})_k$ is a subsequence of $(a_n+b_n)_n$ converging to $a+\limsup(b_n)$.
So, $a + \limsup(b_n)$ is a limit point for $(a_n+b_n)_n$.
Therefore $$\limsup(a_n+b_n) \geq a + \limsup(b_n).$$

---

With this result, the strict inequality is possible only if neither $(a_n)_n$ nor $(b_n)_n$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

First this clearly assumes that the limit of $a_n$ exists (even if its infinite). In which case $\sup_na_n=\lim_na_n$ so the original inequality implies yours.

Answer (score 0):

If the limit of $a_n$ exists, i.e. $a_n \to a$, then
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n = \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = a. $$

So **assuming** that the limit of $(a_n)$ exists, yes.

Comment: Ah I see. As for my first question, when would the inequality be strict?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking for conditions for the equality to hold. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

If $\{a_n\}$ is convergent (otherwise the limit isn't defined), as in your second question, then $\lim \sup \{a_n\} = \lim \{a_n\}$ and so the answer is trivially yes.

Comment: Why does both converging imply that the inequality is strict?